# How to transform date from P20210301 to DD.MM.YYYY in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a date column **P20210301**. How to tranform this date to format **01.03.2021**?

Comment: It sounds like you have formatted *text*, not an actual date datatype. Are you trying to transform your text format, or convert to an actual date datatype?

Comment: `to_date(substr('P20210301', 2), 'yyyymmdd')`

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by converting your text to a date datatype using `TO_DATE`, then converting it to the format you want as a string with `TO_CHAR`

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR (TO_DATE ('P20210301', '"P"YYYYMMDD'), 'DD.MM.YYYY') AS new_date FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: This is much better than my comment with `substr` as it ensures the presence of `P` at the first position.

Answer (score -2):

Database by default date stored in yyyy-mm-dd format so you have to manage a coding side

**Note** :if you use a PHP language then you use a date() function in PHP.

if any other language use like this:

```
TO_CHAR ( TO_DATE (str, 'YYYY/MM/DD'), 'DD.MM.YYYY')
```

Happy Coding...!!

Comment: Dates are stored with an internal 7-byte representation, not with any human-readable format. Your client may be showing YYYY-MM-DD by default, or via your NLS settings, but it isn't stored like that. And the format mask in your `TO_DATE()` call should match the format of the value shown in the question - as already shown in EJ's answer.

Comment: This will fail for the input provided: `P20210301`